# Remote deployment of OS X as an full version upgrade, not a fresh install

Tags: mac-osx, remote, automated-install, osx-mountain-lion

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions (or know if its even possible) to remote upgrade a fleet of Macs from 10.6.8 to 10.7,10.8, or 10.9 remotely. I presume I can push the installESD through ARD, but I want it to run completely unattended.

If it is not possible through "traditional" methods does anyone know of any tools that might help automate this process?

Thank you for your thoughts, feedback, and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, download and use [this script](http://code.google.com/p/munki/downloads/detail?name=createOSXinstallPkg_20120831.zip), called createOSXinstallPkg.
You can find its (simple) [documentation](http://installlionpkg.munki.googlecode.com/git/README.txt), but I recommend you watch the [MacSysAdmin 2012 presentation](http://documentation.macsysadmin.se/Documentation2012/2012doc.html) entitled "More Management for Lion and Mountain Lion" by its developer, Greg Neagle, who manages Disney Animation Studios fleet of Mac.
You don't need to use his popular FOSS [munki](http://code.google.com/p/munki/) deployment management software to deploy the installation package this script creates—ARD, Casper, Absolute Manage, or even a shell script will work just fine—but I recommend it.

Comment: Where is the presentation "More Management for Lion and Mountain Lion" to be found? I'm not seeing it from google or linked from [Greg Neagle's blog](http://managingosx.wordpress.com).

Comment: @joecarroll what is the role of the pkg identifier? do you know if I can deploy through ARD if I create the .pkg in it's default form? Or will it require Munki? Thanks again

Comment: @bmike: Sorry I forgot to link to the presentation; fixed now.

Comment: @DeanA.Vassallo:  If you mean CFBundleIdentifier identifier, in this case, it doesn't really matter. Normally you use it with munki etc. so that e.g. updates can be identified as a particular piece of software. I suggest you read the README, it's short and gives you all you need to know for this particular task.